# Super intricate class values

Tags: css, scrapy, web-crawler

I was checking out some source code as I learn about spiders and found these really intricate class values used in Reddit's CSS: -> [screenshot_of_source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c7DJ.png)

Why do they use these? They seem impossible to work with.
Is it to hinder web crawlers/scrapers from using CSS properties as selectors?

My CSS class and Id names are so specific they leave no doubt what they do. How does anyone work with such an intricate naming standard? Are they generated randomly?

Comment: They are not written by a human, they are autogenerated in the build process.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I thought that but there must be something to learn from them. Is there any indication of what platform or framework was used in the build based on the numbering format, for example? Is there a reason outside of inconveniencing content curation, for them?

Comment: Preventing web scraping most likely has nothing to do with it. They probably use a web framework that minimizes the output code, and part of that minimization includes this kind of HTML classes.